# Union Multiple Text Files

Tags: c#

So I have written the logic to create the union of 2 text files in a folder, viz,

```
public static void UnionFiles()
{
    var dinfo =
        new DirectoryInfo(
            @"C:\http");
    var files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
    IEnumerable<string> _eValA = null;
    IEnumerable<string> _eValB = null;

    _eValA = File.ReadLines(@"C:\http1.txt");
    _eValB = File.ReadLines(@"C:\http2.txt");

    IEnumerable<String> union = _eValA.Union(_eValB);

    File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\union.txt", union.Cast<string>());
}
```

Now I am stuck here, **how do I create the union of multiple files?**

My problem is this: I have multiple files named in ascending timestamps (and the union should respect that) viz.

[image]

**I want to union the first 2 files, then with the result the 3rd file, with the result the 4th file, until we have united all the files and only one final big file is left.**

*Edit*: To avoid confusion, I actually need union and not concatenation.

How can I do that?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You most likely want to use `Concat` instead of `Union`

Comment: I don't want concat, but logical union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested code below but you could loop through the `GetFiles` return value.

```
IEnumerable<string> _currentInput = File.ReadLines(@"C:\http1.txt");

//skip 1 because you've read in the first file assuming it's ordered correctly
foreach(var file in dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt").Skip(1)) 
{
    _currentInput = _currentInput.Union(File.ReadLines(file.FullName));    
}

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\union.txt", _currentInput.Cast<string>());
```

If you're not sure of the first file, you can use a normal `for` loop and skip the union if the index is 0.

Comment: `var file = dinfo` should it be `in`?

Comment: Yes sorry, I copy pasted that line and forgot to change it. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void UnionFiles(string folderPath, string outputFilePath)
{
    var union = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    foreach (string filePath in Directory
                .EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.txt")
                .OrderBy(x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x)))
    {
            union = union.Union(File.ReadAllLines(filePath));
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(outputFilePath, union);
}
```

Note that this is just the basic idea. For instance, it does not perform a check to skip reading files if/when filePath == outputFilePath.

Comment: Editing my answer... Thanks for clarifying.